# Enhanced Look up

Tags: lookup-filter, search-layout, content-search

Say i have an account ABC-12345

I have an enhanced look up for that account in my case. Earlier i would be able to type just ABC in the search and press enter and it would bring this ABC-12345 . but now its not working. i have to type the entire thing for it to search. i don't know what changed.  i went and looked at the search setting to see if the enhanced look up has been enabled but other than that i couldn't think of anything new. 
i am a newbie. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try ABC* as well?

Comment: yes. Nothing works until i enter the exact name in the search box of the look up

Comment: It will be helpful if anyone can point me where to look for that search functionality . it would be helpful. maybe i could go in and look to see if either some code has to be rectified or some filters have to be set. if i am typing something wrong. please feel free to correct me. like i said i am a newbie